Notes claim that a lower semi-continuous function attains its minimum on closed subsets of a Polish space
I am currently reading Touchettes notes: https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0327 on large deviation results and in Appendix B the author states that (in page 81, below eq. B3) that:
The lower semi-continuity of $I$ guarantees that this function achieves its minimum on any closed ses ( a lower semi-continuous function has closed level sets) where $I:\mathcal{X}\to[0,\infty]$ is a lower semi-continuous function on a Polish space. But isn't this claim false? Take $I(x) = x$, $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ and then you have a continuous function on a Polish space, and for a subset $\mathbb{R}=C\subset\mathbb{R}$ you surely do not attain the minimum of $I$.
Edit: I just realized it after posting this question: I suppose that we take the topology of the affinely extended real numbers, where $I$'s classical divergence to $\infty$ does not matter.

Does the theory work if $C$ refers to only compact? Typos are not out of the ordinary in maths.

@ChrisSanders For $C$ compact the theory holds. In particular when the compactness is sequential, the theorem is quite easy to show: pick any minimizing sequence for $\inf_{x\in C}I(x)$ and take any converging subsequence of that. By lower semi-continuity, $I$'s value at the limit of the converging subsequence is at most the liminf along the said subsequence, which is equal to the infimum of $I$ over $C$ by hypothesis. Thus $\inf_{x\in C}I(x)\geq I(y)$ for $y$ the aforementioned limit point, whence $I$ attains its minimum on $C$.

No I meant, is anything in the paper affected by regarding $C$ as compact? Because if not, my approach would be to just assume typo LOL

@ChrisSanders As far as I can tell, nothing prior to that statement in the paper indicates that $C$ should be compact. But, maybe it is the case.
